# How to use gsl_linalg_cholesky_ decomp to composite the lower triangular matrix?

Tags: c++

As we know, [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of $A = L*L^T$.

I tried to write a simple function to decompose the lower triangular matrix $L$. I know there is a C++ function of `GSL/gsl_linalg_cholesky_ decomp` that can do it. I read its manual but I do not quite understand. Anyone can help?

---

I was asked to offer the manual of the function, which is http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Cholesky-Decomposition.html# 1 index-gsl 005flinalg 005fcholesky 005fdecomp-1343

Comment: How about a link to the thing you want us to tell you how to use?

Comment: @Glen_b if you mean the manual, this is the link http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Cholesky-Decomposition.html# 1 index-gsl 005flinalg 005fcholesky 005fdecomp-1343 thanks for stop by!

Comment: Okay, the manual seems utterly clear to me. What's the difficulty?

Comment: @Glen_b ok...please understand there is some stupid people in the world, like me. I do not understand the manual...If you have time could you show a simple sample about how to composite triangle matrix L?

Comment: Don't call yourself stupid - for starters, you immediately imply I'm wasting my time. Second, that wasn't the point...  I can't guess what you don't understand about what it says, since it explicitly tells you where $L$ and $L^T$ are in the output of the function. If you can't understand what it says (which is fine), and *you also can't tell me where the difficulty lies in understanding what it says*, how will me explaining the information again help? If I can't guess where the problem lies and you won't narrow it down, what am I to do? (Lastly, what does "how to composite" mean?)

Comment: @user40596, if you want the simplest pseudocode of Cholesky decomposition, I can give it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you link to takes an input matrix, $A$ (symmetric positive semidefinite), and gives back a matrix with $L$ and $L^T$ in it:

[image]

Both $L$ and $L^T$ include the diagonal (marked in white above).

So if you need for some reason to have $L$ by itself (for many purposes you'll probably be able to use it directly from the returned matrix), you can copy the relevant elements out.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101085/361298)  is outdated or slightly incorrect.
Based on the reference [gsl_linalg_complex_cholesky_decomp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/linalg.html#c.gsl_linalg_complex_cholesky_decomp) (gsl_linalg_cholesky_decomp is deprecated):

> On output the diagonal and lower triangular part of the input matrix A contain the matrix L, while the upper triangular part contains the original matrix.

So, $L^{T}$ is **NOT** on the output result.
If you need $L^{T}$, you just access $L$ with the index of row and column inverted.